# Angular recursive method is not returning value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

I want to find an element with some `id` in multilevel JSON object.
I use recursion with `angular.forEach` method, but the method returns `undefined` even though `return value;` is reached.

Here is method:

```
    function findLaoutFieldByID(array, search) {
        if (!array || !search) {
            return null;
        }
        angular.forEach(array, function(value, key) {
            if (value.id == search) {
                return value;
            }
            return findLaoutFieldByID(value.items, search);
        });
    }sql
```

Maybe someone can tell me why?

Maybe someone can suggest how to find an object with `id=rc2` in this array. I
tried recursion, but had no luck.

```
        $scope.containerLayout = [ {
        id : 'root',
        size : '100%',
        direction : 'row',
        items : [ {
            id : 'rc1',
            size : '50%',
            direction : 'col',
            items : [ {
                id : 'rc11',
                size : '40%'
            }, {
                id : 'rc12',
                size : '40%'
            }, {
                id : 'rc13',
                size : '20%'
            } ]
        }, {
            id : 'rc2',
            size : '50%'
        } ]
    } ];
```

I found some solution, not sure if it is best, but is someone else needs:

```
        function findLaoutFieldByID(array, search) {
        if (!array || !search) {
            return null;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].id == search) {
                return array[i];
            }
            var returns = 0;
            if (array[i].items) {
                while (returns != array[i].items.length) {
                    var val = findLaoutFieldByID(array[i].items, search);
                    if (val == null) {
                        returns++;
                    } else {
                        return val;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You're *returning* from the iteration-function not from `findLaoutFieldByID`.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning from the function that's iterating (angular.forEach), not from `findLaoutFieldByID`. You might want to use a regular `for` loop.